# F# split hex string to chars and get decimal value of each

Tags: f#

Mostly newbie here - did shell scripting and Perl a long time ago. Getting into functional programming (due to not liking OO); dev platform is Windows VS Code, thus starting with F# (as .NET lang), most likely leading to OCaml and/or Haskell. Searching reveals answers in C#/.NET libs, not sure how to access via F#. As example, given cf582f2d5d7d28e18335de05abc54da7, want to get decimal values of each digit (c is 12, f is 15, 5 is 5, so on). Also, seems like Raku does this via split then parse-base(16).

EDIT:
well, I'm trying to do a direct translation from Raku -in REPL:

```
[0] > my $str = 'cf582f2d5d7d28e18335de05abc54da7';
[1] > ( [+] ( for $str.split('', :skip-empty) -> $i { $i.parse-base(16) } ) ) / $str.chars;
```

RETURNS: 8.0625

which 258 (the sum of the hex digits) / 32 (number of hex characters)

While I like Raku, am not sure what it's future is. I like F# very much, and just trying to figure stuff out in fsi. My thinking is this: is there a F# equivalent to `parse-base(16)`? Like maybe in fsi:
`printfn "%i" 'a'.parse-base(16)`
would return 10

Comment: Welcome to F#. I think the best way to address this is for you to post your attempt to solve the problem, and then we can help answer any specific questions you have.

Comment: Wow, the edit can out ugly - sorry

Comment: Thank you, Thomas for cleaning it up.  Guess I should have looked for a guide for how to input things correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a string in hexadecimal format to a decimal integer using the `Convert.ToInt32` function (from the `System` namespace):

```
open System

Convert.ToInt32("ff",16) // returns 255
```

To do the thing that your example is doing, you need to iterate over the digits and then sum the results. You can do this using `map` and `sum`:

```
"cf582f2d5d7d28e18335de05abc54da7"
|> Seq.map (fun c -> Convert.ToInt32(string c, 16))
|> Seq.sum
```

Or even more compactly, using the `sumBy` function:

```
"cf582f2d5d7d28e18335de05abc54da7"
|> Seq.sumBy (fun c -> Convert.ToInt32(string c, 16))
```

Note that you need to use `string c` to convert a character to string (which is what the `ToInt32` function expects).

Comment: YES!! I saw the Convert.ToInt32 function as part of C#/.NET, but wasn't sure how to use in F# (or the right params - (string c, 16))